# What's the difference between "#{self.key}" and "vynd6tg1hh"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

Can anyone explain the difference between `"#{self.key}"` and `"vynd6tg1hh"` when `"#{self.key}"` prints out `"vynd6tg1hh"`?

I have a method where `"#{self.key}"` doesn't work but directly putting in the string does:

```
  def get_wistia_media
    Wistia::Media.get(wistia_key)
  end
```

Doesn't work with:

```
  def wistia_key
    "#{self.key}"
  end
```

Does work with:

```
  def wistia_key
    "vynd6tg1hh"
  end
```

I don't understand it.

EDIT 1:  By 'doesn't work' I mean that the method gets a '404 error' when I use "#{self.key}".

EDIT 2: They're both in my Video model.

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: What is the context, what is self? Are those methods in the same class? I doen't make any sense to me.

Comment: Did you try in the console? What is the output of: `video = Video.first; Wistia::Media.get(video.key.to_s)`?

Comment: Yes, it works fine in the console, just not in rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_wistia_media
  Wistia::Media.get(wistia_key)
end
```

Is calling a class method

```
def wistia_key
  "#{self.key}"
end
```

Is defined as an instance method, try `def self.wistia_key`

```
def wistia_key
  "vynd6tg1hh"
end
```

Just returns a string that will always be the same.

Comment: actually it `returns` that string in the last example.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I should have realised the issue is that it was cycling through all videos, some of which didn't have a key value stored in them.  A massive 'd'oh' moment for me.